# Can not load database

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have a project using CodeIgniter framework. In model class, i try to load data from the database, but the browser return a very very strange result. The page return look like:

```
load->database('demo', TRUE);}function getData(){...} 
(and follow are very much signs like China character +_+)
```

Below is the content of user_model.php:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model 
{
   function __construct() 
   {
       parent::__construct();
       #Line 6: $CI =& get_instance();
       $this->load->database('demo', TRUE);
   }

    function getData()
    {
       $query = $this->db->query("select * from user");

       if ($query->num_rows() < 0)
          show_error('Database is empty!');
       else
          return $query->result();
    }
}
```

I googled very much and got some solutions, but none of them can solved my problem.

- I tried to rewrite the construct function (use $CI and rewrite next line by $CI->load->database('demo', TRUE))
- I tried to use a $db as private variable, assign $this->$db = $this->load->database('demo', TRUE)...

Please help me, i've lost 2 days for this. I can't explain how the China character can display there. It's make me crazy.

P/s: My environment: Window XP SP3 / WAMP server 2.1 / CodeIgniter 2.0.2
All configurations completed and system can run welcome message smoothly.

Comment: First of all grab a tea, calm down and then get in contact with someone who is able to help you and understands your problem. If you already lost two days, then you should find a real person you can talk with and show the code and who has access to the code and system like you have. Doing this remotely is not always possible.

Comment: thank hakre, i asked my colleges but they can not help. I post this question here with hope somebody met same problem can suggest me a way to treat it.

Comment: From the code you posted I have no idea at all I must admit.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is visible in your browser, it seems to me that the script is just output instead of executed. If others php scripts run fine, you probably forgot the opening `<?php` tag in user_model.php.

Comment: No, my file has php opening tag. Do you know why the php code can be display in web browser, and where the CHINA character come from??

Answer (score 0):

```
class User_model extends CI_Model 
{
   function __construct() 
   {
       parent::__construct();
       #Line 6: $CI =& get_instance();
       $DB1 = $this->load->database('demo', TRUE);
   }

    function getData()
    {
       $query = $DB1->query("select * from user");

       if ($query->num_rows() < 0)
          show_error('Database is empty!');
       else
          return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the result is the same. Still display load->database('demo', TRUE);}function getData().. and CHINA CHARACTER.